# Typo3 backend-module Database functions

Tags: php, module, typo3, kickstarter

*sigh* another T3 related question - I try to find examples and tutorials on the web, but they seem to hide themselves very well...

It's about T3 v4.5

I created a backend(!) module with kickstarter, which - sorta - worked.

I actually expected kickstarter to create a dummy-form when I create a db-table and its fields, but that was wishful thinking.

So I created my own form, with fields and buttons and I do receive the form contents in the index.php script.

But now I have no idea how to save this data to the database. I found the tca.php file which looks like the model of the db-table. But I can't find any tutorial that tells me how to use it.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approch is... using TYPO3's form for record editing, just instead of creating own form, check on the List view how links to *Create* and *Edit* forms are created and use the same syntax in your list view.

You'll save many hours of stress.

BTW: nobody hides nothing :) TYPO3 [publishes whole database API on dedicated page](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/45/html/classt3lib___d_b.html)